# Using a 64bit DLL wiht 32 Borland C++ Builder

Tags: c++, dll, 64-bit, c++builder

I need to make a "data pool" of more than 4GB data, organized as 2 dimensional data arrays:

I have a 50 forms application made in 32bit CodeGear 2009 C++ Builder with many third party VCL components - thus not really an option right now to migrate to Visual Studio 2010 ( for now ).

The idea is to use a 64Bit DLL ( made with Visual Studio 2010 ? Or Delphi EX2 ? ) containing the data arrays - the idea is to call the 64bit DLL with x,y parameters of the data location in the array, and the DLL returns the value from the array.

Anyone have made such before ? Is it possible to call a 64Bit DLL from C++ Builder, how would the init code look like for dynamically loading the DLL at runtime ?

Any input is very much appreciated, as this is a show stopper.

Answer (score 4):

Your best option, given the constraints you list, is to use an out-of-proc COM server. Your 32 bit C++Builder app cannot load 64 bit modules. That's a hard limitation that cannot be bypassed. This leaves you with some form of inter-process communication and out-of-proc COM will be the easiest to code.

Comment: "COM server" could mean that Windows and a range of processes will be involved in which should be a simpel transfer of a float value from application A to application B, perhaps  100.000 instructions to get a float value ?

Comment: Well, do you want to solve the problem or not? You can't crack the 32 bit address space limit without a 64 bit process!

Comment: Alternative is ofcause to save the data on the HDD - but this is too slow. The 64 bit adress problem arrises if I pass a pointer to a memory location to the 64 bit DLL - a possible solution is to call the DLL with row, coulmn  in the array ( and not with a memory pointer ) - and that the DLL returns the array value, not a pointer to the memory location.

Comment: Perhpas to use a known Windwos API memory location to pass the data ? Such as graphics, keyboard, - any Windows API parameter which is globally accessible, and with a direct pointer not a function call ? The DLL could hook a Windowes API call, thus the 32Bit allication call the hooked function ( a function in the 64bit DLL ), the DLL returns the value in a Windows API memory location ?

Comment: You can't load the DLL. You can share memory with memory mapped files but then you have to synchronise and signal. COM out of proc is your best bet. Your expectations are too high.

Comment: Then not use a DLL, but a 64bit application - which hooks one of the Windows API calls, and communicate with the 32bit application through this standard interface. In the good old DOS days, this was possible.

Comment: No, you need another process.

Comment: What if I let the 64bit application start the 32bit application, that would be a 64bit session ? Would that provide a fast method to communicate data between the two ?

Answer (score 3):

A 32-bit program cannot load a 64-bit DLL. DLLs are loaded into the running process, and it's the process as a whole that's 32 or 64-bit. You could, at best, create a separate 64-bit application and launch that from your 32-bit application; you could then make the two communicate in pretty much whatever way you like. [This is how IIS is able to let 64-bit Windows serve web applications using 32-bit DLLS.](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/13f991a5-45eb-496c-8618-2179c3753bb0.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Thanks hvd - thus the problem is narrowed to how to best exchange a value ( int/float/double ) between two applications ( a 32bit and a 64bit application ) with minimum overhead. Any suggetion of which method would provide the fastest "communication" of values ?

Comment: No idea, sorry, but is the overhead really going to be a problem? You're not going to send one message/call one function/... for each byte you want to retrieve. Use whatever is easiest for you to program, whatever you have most experience with.